# document.activeElement can not get target element

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

```js
editor.onmouseup = editclick;
editor.onkeydown=editinput;
function editclick(e) {
  info.innerHTML += '<br>' + document.activeElement.textContent
}
function editinput(e) {
  info.innerHTML += '<br>' + document.activeElement.textContent
}
```

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" class="" tabIndex="1">
  <span>diyige span</span> saosuoasueousameli
</div>
<div id="info"></div>
```

when i click/keyin on the `<span>deerge span</span>`, the info will show all editor div. so how can i show only `<span>deerge span</span>` ?

Comment: A `span` must have a `tabindex` attribute with a non-negative value, otherwise it can never be the `activeElement`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.activeElement` will return the element that currently has the *focus*. In your case, the one element that grabs the focus is the container <div>.
You'd have to set the `tabindex` attribute on your <span> element for it to be focusable, but doing so in your *contenteditable* area is not that practical.

Instead you probably want the [Range.commonAncestorContainer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/commonAncestorContainer) element, which will be the deepest Node where the current selection actually is, so in your case, where the cursor is. In case of collapsed selection, it should be the TextNode where the cursor is, you can retrieve the Element through its `.parentNode` property.

```js
editor.onmouseup = editclick;
editor.onkeydown=editinput;
function editclick(e) {
  let focus_elem = getElemAtCursor();
  info.innerHTML += '<br>' + focus_elem.textContent;
}
function editinput(e) {
  const focus_elem = getElemAtCursor();
  info.innerHTML += '<br>' + focus_elem.textContent;
}

function getElemAtCursor() {
 const elem = getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
 return elem.nodeType === 1 ? elem : elem.parentNode;
}
```

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" class="">
  <span>diyige span</span> saosuoasueousameli
</div>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for your solution, but in chrome the commonAncestorContainer is the textnode in the span element, not the span element themself.  do i right?

Comment: @马长昆michaelbergman yes you are right, sorry, in case of collapsed range that should also be a Node, not an Element will edit (you just need a simple check in that case `if( focus_elem.nodeType !== 1 ) focus_elem = focus_elem.parentNode`

Comment: Edited so that when you click/type in "saosuoasueousameli" it returns the parent div. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: thank you, i got it. this topic maybe not have a really simple solution, and your solution maybe is the only solution. because i find dom4 spec yesterday, and i think maybe we got element not need range/selection api, so i ask this question, but now, i think maybe no element api for this directly. any way, thank you for you explain patiently.

Answer (score 1):

Use `e.target.textContent`

For mouse events this works, but for keyboard events for nested `contenteditable` elements, you need to apply a small hack:

Set the `contenteditable="true"` for the `span` and wrap it with another `span` having `contenteditable="false"`

Check below code:

```js
editor.onmouseup = editclick;
editor.onkeypress = editKey;

function editclick(e) {
  info.innerHTML += '<br>' + e.target.textContent
}

function editKey(e) {
  info.innerHTML += '<br>' + e.target.textContent
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" class="" tabIndex="0">
  <span contenteditable="false">
    <span contenteditable="true">contenteditable span</span>
  </span><br/>
  contenteditable div content comes here. contenteditable div content comes here.
</div>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: thank you, this is right for mouse event, but how can i do it for keyboard event? just like:  editor.onkeydown

Comment: @马长昆michaelbergman Hi, for keyboard there is a small hack, please check my edited answer and explanation

Comment: thank you, let think about it, because i make a little pure text editor for a knowledge website, so i don/t sure if i can use this solution, any way, thank you:) you have open a window for me.